# Qt creator debug string (show content)

Tags: string, qt, debugging, stl, qt-creator

I'm using QT Creator 3.0.0, clang 3.5 and gdb debugger. When i want to see string value in debugger i have to expand six items to see string content by one letter in a row. Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

How can i see string content easier?

I also can't see content of vector and other containers.

Comment: You may use `Show View Contents in Editor` action in dock`s context menu

Comment: "Show View Contents in Editor" definitely helps

Comment: No, it doesn't show values, just structure. I want to see value of string without any expands in neighboring column "Value" (in perfect case, at least).

Comment: If the problem is just in convenient string representation then [debug helpers](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugging-helpers.html) can help you

Comment: std::strings print just fine in Debugging mode

Comment: I had debug helper enabled but it doesn't help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For QT Creator 4.10, right-click on the variable you want to inspect and choose **Change Value Display Format** option, then select **UTF-8 String in Separate Window**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine right from factory.
Did you check if the "Enable Debugging Helpers" option in context menu from the locals/variable view is enabled.